# Recreate OCR Salesforce Object

Tags: apex

I've created a custom object called Close Plan Contact Role (CPCR). My plan is to use a scheduled apex class to periodically move data from Opportunity Contact Role (OppCR) and into CPCR every hour. My code is below. Can someone please help fix what's wrong?

```
public class addOppCRtoCPCR {

    public addOppCRtoCPCR() {

        Map<Id,String> OppCRlMap = new Map<Id,String>();

        // Query all Close Plan contact roles.

        List<Close_Plan_Contact_Role__c> CPCRList     = [ SELECT id, Contact__c, IsDeleted__c, IsPrimary__c, Opportunity__c, Role__c
                                                          FROM Close_Plan_Contact_Role__c ];

        // Query all Opportunity contact roles. Place them in a list
        List<OpportunityContactRole> OppCRlist      = [ SELECT id, ContactId, IsDeleted, IsPrimary, OpportunityId, Role
                                                        FROM OpportunityContactRole ];

                            /* ADD MISSING RECORDS FROM OppCRlist to CPCRList */

        // If OppCRlist is larger than CPCRList, add missing contacts to CPCRList
        if(OppCRlist.size() > CPCRList.size()){            

            for(Integer i = 0; i < OppCRlist.size(); i++ ){
                OppCRlMap.put(OppCRlist.id, 'NoValue');
            }

            // Loop through OppCRlist
            for(Close_Plan_Contact_Role__c CPCR : CPCRList){

                if(!OppCRlMap.contains(CPCR)){

                    // Create a new Close_Plan_Contact_Role__c record
                    <Close_Plan_Contact_Role__c> CPCRrecord = new <Close_Plan_Contact_Role__c>();

                    // populate Close_Plan_Contact_Role__c fields
                    CPCRrecord.Contact__c       = CPCR.ContactId;
                    CPCRrecord.IsDeleted__c     = CPCR.IsDeleted;
                    CPCRrecord.IsPrimary__c     = CPCR.IsPrimary;
                    CPCRrecord.Opportunity__c   = CPCR.OpportunityId;
                    CPCRrecord.Role__c          = CPCR.Role;

                    // Add new record to set
                    CPCRList.add(CPCRrecord);
                }
            }
        insert CPCRList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What IS Wrong? It would be extremely helpful if you could let us know so we do not have to spend a lot of time looking for issues that may not even be what you are asking about. Also good to review [Ask]

Comment: Everything looks right to me, but SFDC keeps giving generic errors like:  Error: Compile Error: expecting right curly bracket, found '<' at line 30 column 20

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is here:

```
<Close_Plan_Contact_Role__c> CPCRrecord = new <Close_Plan_Contact_Role__c>();
```

Should be:

```
Close_Plan_Contact_Role__c CPCRrecord = new Close_Plan_Contact_Role__c();
```

Not sure why you thought the < > were needed

Comment: total brain fart on my part.

Comment: it happens to all of us